# Why does my SQL Server Schema Compare get very slow?

Tags: sql-server, schema-compare

We have a MS sqlproject where a database project references multiple vendor databases. In other projects, schema compare is very fast, but in this project, schema compare has gotten as slow as 20 minutes.  That's unuseable.

What could be causing this?
How can I diagnose?

Comment: Schema compare speed depends on the number of objects that are present in a database. If for example a database has thousands of stored procedure schema compare can be extremely slow.

Comment: Attach SQL Profiler to see what's being executed. That can give you a hint. Or, use PerfView to profile devenv.exe and see what function names are on the stack.